# Error callback without any error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm executing the following in my JS.

```
var url = ...;
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  error: function(p1, p2) { alert(p2); }
});
```

I get the text *error* but when I check the console of FF, it lists the call to the address specified as *200 OK*. It appears that I **do** get an error, because *success* isn't called though.

1. How is it possible?
2. Where can I check the message of the error (I see *state()* says *rejected*)?

Comment: add a third parameter to the function and it should contain the error message

Comment: @Snowburnt Nope. It says *undefined*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of a cross-domain request failure.

On the network level, the request succeeds (which is why Firefox shows you a `200 OK` response), but the same origin policy (SOP) triggers an error and stops JavaScript from reading the response.

If you want to make the request succeed, either:

- Have the requested server serve the appropriate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header for your requesting origin. (This is only possible if you control the target server.)
- Use JSONP: have the server send you the data in script format, and have your client run it in a `<script>` tag. (Again, the target server must support this already.)
- Set up your own server to proxy the HTTP request and forward the response to your script:

  ```
  Client Ajax ==> Your server (allowed by SOP) ==> Target resource
  ```

  Note that this will not forward cookies, so if the traget resource requires authentication, that authentication will fail.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Do you control the requested server? JSONP requires server-side code, so you if the server doesn't implement it already, you need to add it. (And if you have the power to implement it, why not just add CORS headers?) If you don't control the target server, you can use another server that you *do* control (and *is* allowed by the SOP) to act as a proxy.

Comment: In the current situation I don't control much. And, even worse, I can't design it in the suggested way. I'm starting to be afraid that I won't be able to build what I need with the tools that I've got...

Comment: @KonradViltersten Another "solution" is to make whatever you're building into a JS/HTML-based browser extension or app, which would not be subject to the SOP. Or, you can use a Flash plugin to send cross-domain TCP. If you wan't to get around the SOP and can't control the server, you'll need to depart from the Web API in some way: either by making a non-Web page, or by plugin. Good luck!